# Marterialize initializing Autocomplete inside Modal inside shadowroot not working

Tags: java, html, typescript, google-chrome-extension, materialize

I´m trying to code a little chrome extension useing Materialize.
To avoid materialize interfering with the opened website i only use it inside the shadowroot which i insert into the website.

The problem only appears when trying to initialize an Autocomplete instance inside the opened Modal.

**The input html looks like:**

```
<input id="goalInput" class="col s9 autocomplete" placeholder="">
```

**Trying to initialize:**

```
 var autocompleteInstance = M.Autocomplete.init(shadowRoot.getElementById('goalInput'));
 // or
 var autocompleteInstance = M.Autocomplete.init(shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete'));
```

*Both queries are working and !== null;*

**Produces following error**:

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQiek.png) Stackoverflow wont let me add png direktly yet:

The error happens somewhere inside materialize initialization ( i think when trying to create a dropdown or something, i might be wrong here).

I already searched for a really long time but maybe i was missing the right keywords to find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.

The problem was materialize.js trying to find the initialized dropdown within the normal html which excludes the shadowRoot.

```
  _this9.dropdownEl = document.getElementById(_this9.id);
  if(_this9.dropdownEl === null) {
    _this9.dropdownEl = document.getElementById('shadowWrapper').shadowRoot.getElementById(_this9.id);
  }
```

I just updated the code from materialize.js to work with my extension.